# BMGlyphJustifyLeft doesn't seem to be working fine in Swift (SpriteKit)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm creating a Swift (SpriteKit) game where I have my score. I'm using BMGlyph Library and Software to add a custom font/label to my game.

Here's how i create the entire bmglyph label & font:

```
let bestScoreFont = BMGlyphFont(name: "scorefont_small_gold")
self.bestScoreLabel = BMGlyphLabel.init(text: "best 0", font: bestScoreFont)
self.bestScoreLabel.zPosition = ZIndexPosition.HUD
self.bestScoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: 70, y: self.FRAME_HEIGHT - 20)
self.bestScoreLabel.textJustify = BMGlyphJustifyLeft
```

Now, this label as you may see, it's being placed on the **left-upper corner**.

The problem is, that if the player does a huge score or whatever the score is, the label moves to the left as the text grows instead of remaining aligned left and growing right. I don't know if I'm explaining myself correctly.

Tested with different values on the score, and the longer it gets, the deeper it goes through the left side of the screen.

For instance, i tested adding a huge value like 123123123123123. This is how it looks:

[image]

Horrible, right? haha.

Anyways, does anyone know how to solve this? and make it stick in the same place left-aligned?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: BMGlyphLabel is a custom library where is an open issue about alignment and positioning https://github.com/tapouillo/BMGlyphLabel/issues/13. However this problem is not fixed, according to the author words: "As it is now, BMGlyphLabel is almost unusable.."

Comment: I think you want to use a outlined label, I don't try this but seems to be more stable: https://github.com/marioklaver/MKOutlinedLabelNode

Comment: Oh lol, didn't see that coming... i will try that one out :) thank you sir! i will let you know.

Comment: Whoops, look at the documentation "Draw outlined text in SpriteKit. Currently only SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.Center is supported" :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, looks like I found a way to do it with BMGlyph. Although there's a registered issue as @Alessandro Ornano told me. 
There are 2 attributes to set alignment in BMGlyph.
1) textJustify
2) horizontalAlignment & verticalAlignment

The one it works is the 2nd. And by placing BMGlyphHorizontalAlignmentLeft as a value. Tested BMGlyphHorizontalAlignmentRight and works as well.